# How to scroll grid Windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a settings page with several Textbox component inside 4 different stack panels. 
Every panels are in a Grid component :

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,30" Grid.Row="0">...

    <StackPanel Name="stackSettings" Grid.Row="1">...

    <StackPanel Name="stackCustomSettings" Grid.Row="2">...

    <StackPanel Name="stackSaveSettings" Grid.Row="3">...

</Grid>
```

How can I modify my xaml so the grid scroll vertically ?

Comment: Have you tried to use [ScrollViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx)?

Comment: I tried to put the grid inside a ScrollViewer but nothing changed... No error and half of my component were still out of the page.

Comment: As I've tried it should work, when you add just `<ScrollViewer>` above the grid. Can you share a sample project with the problem? Also is using so many stackpanels necessary, thay are one above another, so it could be just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is working for me:

```
<Page>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,30" Grid.Row="0">...

            <StackPanel Name="stackSettings" Grid.Row="1">...

            <StackPanel Name="stackCustomSettings" Grid.Row="2">...

            <StackPanel Name="stackSaveSettings" Grid.Row="3">...
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

What is your parent element ? A StackPanel ?

Comment: Yep you are right, works fine for me. I think I didn't put the ScrollViewer markup at the wrong place in the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt of all, this code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Your content -->
</Grid>
```

Equals this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <!-- Your content -->
</StackPanel>
```

Because each row has its height set to `Auto`, which means the whole `Grid` will be as high as its content. If you want it to be scrollable, just place it inside `ScrollViewer`. However, the `ScrollViewer` cannot be inside of `StackPanel` or `Grid` with row height set to `Auto`, because it won't scroll.

Working example:

```
<Page>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <!--Place your controls here-->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

Comment: You are right, I can merge some of them. But I still need the other since I add dynamically controls in specific StackPanels